# Counting unordered partitions on nested concentric disks

Tags: reference-request, generating-functions, integer-partitions

The idea is to think of each layer outside of the [core] as a rotatable disk and then only count a single member from each of the resulting equivalence classes, which I think can be done by requiring that the addends are non-increasing from the core to the surface as well as when proceeding counter-clockwise from $0$ rad. For example, the invalid partitions

```
11[2]2  2[2]11
```

of $6$ are equivalent to

```
1[2]21
```

For $1,2,3,4,5$ I count the following $1,2,4,8,15$ partitions (resp.):

```
[1]

[2]  [1]1

[3]  [2]1  [1]11  1[1]1
                                                 1
[4]  [3]1  [2]2  [2]11  1[2]1  [1]111  1[1]11  1[1]1
                                                               1                                  1       1
[5]  [4]1  [3]2  [3]11  1[3]1  [2]21  1[2]2  [2]111  1[2]11  1[2]1  [1]1111  1[1]111   11[1]11  1[1]11  1[1]1
                                                                                                          1
```

I also counted $28$ partitions of $6$, but I'm not sure if that number is right. I haven't found any promising leads in oeis, but it seems likely that something is known about this kind of partition.

I'm hoping for further terms for the corresponding partition function, a generating function, or a source with more information.

Edit: I realized that the circular version of Young tableaux is essentially the same as the original. That is, if you flip the Young tableaux for a shape with $n$ cells upside-down and wrap it around $n+1$, you get the circular Young tableaux for the corresponding circular Young diagram. I don't think that says much about this problem, but perhaps there is a nice connection to plane partitions if we unwrap our partitions. In particular (if $n$ is the number we're partitioning), I guess we want plane partitions of $n-k-a$ for $a\geq0$ and with $k$ the greatest part of the partition.

Comment: I also got 28 for 6 and saw a promising pattern.  Consider these partitions of 6 with [2].  There are p(2) = 2 of your partitions with parts [2]22 and p(3) = 3 with parts [2]211 and p(4) = 5 with parts [2]1111.  Then there are p(5) = 7 with [1]11111.  Grouping by descending core number, 28 = (p(0)) + (p(1)) + (p(1)+p(2)) + (p(1)+p(2)+p(3)) + (p(2)+p(3)+p(4)) + (p(5)) = 1 + 1 + 3 + 6 + 10 + 7.  This needs some work to be generalized, but the count for 7 should be (p(0)) + (p(1)) + (p(1)+p(2)) + (p(1)+p(2)+p(3)) + (p(2)+p(2)+p(3)+p(4))+(p(3)+p(4)+p(5)) + (p(6)) = 49.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you started to say in your edit, this all comes down to plane partitions.

An expression for the number of your partitions of $n$ is
$$ \sum_{c=1}^n pp(n-c,c) $$
($c$ for [core]) where $pp(i,j)$ is the number of plane partitions of $i$ with largest part $j$; this triangle of numbers is given in [OEIS A242642](http://oeis.org/A242642) (with references back to MacMahon), which is the cumulative version of [A091355](http://oeis.org/A091355). Note that if $j\geq i$ then $pp(i,j) = pp(i)$, the (unrestricted) number of plane partitions of $i$.  Here are the next few values for the number of your partitions.
$$6: pp(5,1) + pp(4,2) + pp(3) + pp(2) + pp(1) + pp(0) = 7 + 10 + 6 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 28.$$
$$7: pp(6,1) + pp(5,2) + pp(4,3) + pp(3) + pp(2) + pp(1) + pp(0) \\ =  11 + 16 + 12 + 6 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 50.$$
$$8: pp(7,1) + pp(6,2) + pp(5,3) + pp(4) + pp(3) + pp(2) + pp(1) + pp(0) \\ =  15 + 29 + 21 + 13 + 6 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 89.$$
$$9: pp(8,1) + pp(7,2) + pp(6,3) + pp(5,4) + pp(4) + pp(3) + pp(2) + pp(1) + pp(0) \\ =  22 + 45 + 40 + 23 + 13 + 6 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 154.$$
$$10: pp(9,1) + pp(8,2) + pp(7,3) + pp(6,4) + pp(5) + pp(4) + pp(3) + pp(2) + pp(1) + pp(0) \\ =  30 + 75 + 67 + 45 + 24 + 13 + 6 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 265.$$

(The computation for $n=7$ in my comment was off by 1 for not counting 2 2 | 1 and 2 1 | 2 separately in the cases with [2].)  Curiously, the enumeration of your partitions matches [A036615](http://oeis.org/A036615) up to $n=8$ but that sequence's next terms are 155 and 267; still, there may be some connection to limited height $k$-ary rooted trees.